Issue when creating new project with existing spfx project using teams toolkit
I have created a default SPFx project as mentioned in the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part
It is working as expected while I execute the gulp serve command. Please refer to the below screenshot as a proof.


Now, I am trying to create a new team project with an existing SPFx project.
For that I have taken reference from the below link,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-spfx?tabs=vscode%2Cviscode&tutorial-step=2
I have selected the "import an Existing SPFx Solution" option in Step-6.
When I try to preview my app in Teams using the "Preview Your Teams App(F5)" option from Visual Studio Code.

It threw the below error in the Teams

Can anyone help me with the same?
Thanks

I've replied in GitHub issue, will use that one to track
